# How do I find out which function is used for zsh tab completion

Tags: zsh-completion

I want to know which function zsh is using for tab completion of a command.
For many commands (`make`, `ls`, `cd` …) I can apparently guess `_<COMMANDNAME>`, but I might actually have overriden this setting with `compdef _mycd cd`.

The reasons why I want to know this are two:

1. I might want to read some function definitions to use parts of them in functions I'm writing
2. I want to wrote a completion function which itself calls the completion for other commands (like one does in `_nice`, with the exception that I might not rely on `shift; CURRENT--; _normal`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current completion rules are stored in `$_comps`.
So one can display the completion rule for `cd` with `echo $_comps[cd]` and display the actual function definition with `functions $_comps[cd]`.